# How to logout specific session user

Tags: php, session, session-variables, logout

I have a login system, where two types of users can log in: employers and members.
Both have their own login function that checks for id and passwords and sets the session to their name.
Also I have a log out php code where I am destroying the session.
I login the employer and then log in the member and everything is working, but when I click the logout they both get logged out.
How can I logout only a specific user and allow the other to still navigate.

> here I am checking what members wants to log in and sending the id, password and the type of member to the function.

```
$id = $_POST['inputID'];
        $pass = $_POST['inputPassword'];
        $member = $_POST['appUser'];

        if ($member == 'Member' )
            {   
                $member_query->logIn($id, $pass);

                if(isset($_SESSION['session_member_first_name']) )
                    {   
                        echo "<h2>Welcome: </h2><h4>".$_SESSION['session_member_first_name']."</h4> 
                        <a href = 'view_members.php'> Click here </a>";

                    }
                else {echo "Credential do not match out database records";} 
            }

            elseif ($member == 'Employer')
            {
                $admin_query->logIn($id, $pass);
                if(isset($_SESSION['session_user_first_name']) )
                    {
                        echo "<h2>Welcome: </h2><h4>".$_SESSION['session_user_first_name']."</h4> 
                        <a href = 'view_members.php'> Click here </a>";

                    }
                else {echo "Credential do not match our database records";} 
            }
```

> here I check if id and password match against my DB and setting the session.

```
if($id == $dbuser_id and $password == $dbpassword)
        {
            session_start();

            $_SESSION['session_user_first_name'] = $dbuser_first_name;
            $_SESSION['session_user_last_name'] = $dbuser_last_name;
            $_SESSION['session_user_id'] = $dbuser_id;
            $_SESSION[‘last_acted_on’] = time();
        }
```

> this is my logout

```
        <?php
        session_start(); 
        session_destroy(); 
        header("location: index.html"); 
        ?>
```

p.s I am logging both users from same browser, don't know if this matters.
Thanks

Comment: You destroy the whole session. Don't do that.Put their session info in different session variables and only unset those values.

Comment: Can a user be an Member and an Employer at the same time? So there's like a two-tiered authentication system?

Comment: @Halcyon No. members are different from employers.

Comment: @Otonel are you performing the logins in the same browser context or are you using something like in-private browsing that doesn't share sessions between windows? Because if you're sharing the browser context your login as Employer will override the login as Member since you can only have one session per browser context. You can also test with two different browsers of course 8)

Comment: @JohnConde What do you mean to put their session info in a different session variable. And how can I check which one to unset?

Comment: I think John may have had the same idea as me, in that you have a two-tiered authentication system.

Comment: Well .. that doesn't work. You're saying "Hi, I'm Jack" then you say "Hi, I'm Jill" and then you log out. Well, Jack was already gone when you logged in as Jill :P does that help you understand what is going on?

Comment: @If I leave it like this, will it work if two members logged in from two different browsers?

Comment: Ok, so your code works like it should, you're just doing something odd. I don't think there are many websites that will restore a previous session after logging in as a different user. You can certainly make it behave that way but I don't see why you should. - Yes it will work. You can test it with two different browsers, or from two different machines (or in-private sessions).

Comment: @Halcyon It works fine from different browsers. Should I also use "unset_session in my php logout?

Comment: I don't know what `unset_session` is. Do you mean `session_unset()`? You could, but I think `session_destroy()` is enough

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, I meant session_unset(). Thanks anyway for the good example with Jack&Jill ;)